# Install Cowsay issues

Tags: software-installation

Can anyone assist with installing Cowsay?  I've got Ubuntu 14.04 TLS.  I've tried various commands and websites to download it, but get no joy.  I get messages such as: *invalid operation.*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please give us a bit more information like: How did you try to install it? Where did you get it from? What the *exact* error message is?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: what are you using to install it?

Comment: The command to install it from a terminal is `sudo apt-get install cowsay`. You have to be an admin user to run sudo-commands though!

Comment: Thanks guys.  I got it running thanks to: sudo apt-get update and then: sudo apt-get install cowsay.  Rupdawg from the Udacity course gave me that tip.  I think the update command was the .